# Making a shift function in 2048

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let us say i have a list:

```
board = [2, 4, 0, 2, 8, 4, 4, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2]
```

and i already have some code that will make the list be displayed like this:

```
2 4 0 2
8 4 4 8
0 2 0 0
4 0 2 2
```

So is there a way for me to remove every 0 from each row and add it back in the end(even if there are different values in the list) so that the board now looks like:

```
2 4 2 0
8 4 4 8
2 0 0 0
4 2 2 0
```

I want to do this using a loop and not individually having to write separate code for each row.

Also can you do this without making the initial list to

```
board = [[2, 4, 0, 2], [8, 4, 4, 8], [0, 2, 0, 0], [4, 0, 2, 2]]
```

The code for 1 row would be :

```
board = [2, 0, 0, 2]
k = len(board)
board[:] = (value for value in board if value != 0)
while len(board) < k:
    board.append(0)
print(board)

Output = [2, 2, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `list.count`:

```
board = [2, 4, 0, 2, 8, 4, 4, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2]
new_board = [board[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(board), 4)]
final_board = [list(filter(None, i))+([0]*i.count(0)) for i in new_board]
last_board = [i for b in final_board for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4, 4, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0]
```

Comment: I don't want the output to have lists inside of lists. That would mess up the rest of my code.

Comment: Then concatenate the lists?

Comment: So this is to shift right, is there any way you can make it so that this works on board[0], board[4], board[8], board[12]

Comment: @J.Doe Can you clarify what you mean by shifting, specifically how `board[value]` factors into the shift?

Comment: So if you play 2048, you know there is shifting left right down and up. Left and right are easier since they are in rows but down and up are harder since there indexes are apart from eachother. I need board[0], board[4], board[8], board[12] because in the list, they are the values that make up the first column.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes there is nothing wrong with a simple loop:

```
board = [2, 4, 0, 2, 8, 4, 4, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2]

x=4
nb=[]
for e in zip(*[iter(board)]*x):
    ne=[se for se in e if se!=0]
    nb.extend(ne+[0]*(x-len(ne)))  #.append if you want to maintain sub lists

>>> nb
[2, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4, 4, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's a one-liner using some of Python's functional tools. The key ingredients are [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial), [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), and [`operator.not_`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.not_), all of which come from the [Functional Programming Modules](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functional.html#functional-programming-modules) section of Python's standard library documentation.

```
>>> import functools, itertools, operator
>>> board = [2, 4, 0, 2, 8, 4, 4, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(functools.partial(sorted, key=operator.not_), zip(*[iter(board)]*4))))
[2, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4, 4, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0]
```

Most of the work here is in turning the linear representation of the board into a nested list-of-lists representation, and then turning it back again. Here it is step-by-step.

First, turning the flat representation into a nested one:

```
>>> nested = list(zip(*[iter(board)]*4))
>>> nested
[(2, 4, 0, 2), (8, 4, 4, 8), (0, 2, 0, 0), (4, 0, 2, 2)]
```

I've added that extra outer `list` call just to show the contents of the `zip` iterable. It's not necessary once all the steps are put together. Now sort each row with a suitable key to move the zeros to the right:

```
>>> sorted_nested = list(map(functools.partial(sorted, key=operator.not_), nested))
>>> sorted_nested
[[2, 4, 2, 0], [8, 4, 4, 8], [2, 0, 0, 0], [4, 2, 2, 0]]
```

Again, the outer list call is unnecessary, and we'll lose it when we put everything together. A key point here is that Python's [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function provides a stable sort, so the nonzero elements stay in the same order with respect to each other. Finally, flatten back into a list:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sorted_nested))
[2, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4, 4, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0]
```

Putting this all together, and removing the unnecessary inner conversions to list, you get the one liner at the top of this post.

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(functools.partial(sorted, key=operator.not_), zip(*[iter(board)]*4))))
[2, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4, 4, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0]
```